# MQTT sending object instead of string in Nest.js Transport

Tags: asynchronous, mqtt, nestjs

When I am trying to send a string from my Nest.js backend, it is wrapping the string into a JSON object. Hence I am getting an object instead of a plain string. Since I can't change the code at the receiver, I need to send it as a plain string only.

**IMPORT**:

```
import { ClientProxy, MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
```

**INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR**:

```
@Inject('MQTT_CLIENT') private _mqtt: ClientProxy,
```

**INSIDE FUNCTION**:

```
this._mqtt.emit<any,string>('xyz/ABC', packet.toString()).toPromise();
```

Packet sent: "sfdksjhfoyoasoiuoudoiuasoidoiaiusoida"

Packet received:

```
{
  "pattern": "xyz/ABC",
  "data": "sfdksjhfoyoasoiuoudoiuasoidoiaiusoida"
}
```

Packet wanted at receiver: "sfdksjhfoyoasoiuoudoiuasoidoiaiusoida"

Comment: If doing so using the default Transport library is not possible, I am open to using other fairly established libraries.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, MQTT will send both pattern and data, You can use `Dot Notation` to extract the property you need.

Comment: So you mean I need to edit the code at the Receiver end(written in python), as I mentioned changing that code is not possible for me. Is there any other library which helps us do that?

Comment: Also, when I am trying to Subscribe to that packet at Nestjs, it is un-wrapping it automatically and giving us back in form of a string only.

Comment: Well, the Nest.js receiver also gets the whole object and just give you the data property, if it has to be MQTT what you did is the best approach and I don't know any other libraries. but the fact that you cant change the reciever-end is kinda weird.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the nest library under the hood converts the JSON object back string. When I say I cannot change the receiver code, I mean that it is the least preferred option for me since it is at the Firmware level of the IoT devices. Can you please guide me to the documentation if there is which confirms your fact, so that we opt for the receiver code change option if that is the last standing option.

Comment: @AkashGoyal did you get somewhere with this